# Who's in the portrait next to Karen Page?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, daredevil-2015

In *Daredevil* season 3, episode 10, the story initially takes place some time in the past where Karen Page is attending a college (university) party.

In one scene you can see her to the right of a portrait which is quite prominently & clearly shown:

[image]

Who is this a portrait of (either in or out of universe)?

I didn't see any shots where the visible nameplate was actually legible. But maybe he is recognizable.

The approximate date seemed to be maybe 10 years earlier than the main storyline (guesstimate) which would make it around 2005, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 8):

A [reverse image search](https://tineye.com/search) on https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkSF9.jpg turns up that is just a standard stock image, sold by a number of [image](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/young-businessman-posing-in-studio-portrait-royalty-free-image/57260633) [providers](https://www.istockphoto.com/ca/photo/young-businessman-posing-in-studio-portrait-gm57260633-13312314) online.

[image: getty images]